# Which sorted collection implementation has the smallest memory footprint in Java?

Tags: java, collections, libraries

I'm not unduly bothered about read/write performance (though obviously as fast as possible is always good), rather I'm looking for a sorted collection implementation that is as memory efficient as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you *could* store the data in compressed form in memory which would give you close to optimal memory usage, but the performance would really suck. I suggest instead that you look for a sensible tradeoff between memory and perfomance, and just buy more memory for your computer if necessary. Memory is cheap.

Comment: And if your data is really, *really* big (multi gigabyte or terabyte) you should probably store it in a database instead of in memory, and put an index on the column you use to look up. Obviously this is much, much slower than storing it in memory, but since the data is persisted to disk you are limited only by disk capacity, not memory.

Answer (score 3):

Well then just store it in array of exactly the size you need, and sort it. one time work of O(n log n), and each search thereafter is O(log n). You can easily convrted the sorted array to a List with Arrays.asList().

Comment: If you know how many elements you're going to have, you could make an ArrayList without wasting any space, which would be slightly easier to use.

Comment: if you don't know up front how many items you'll have then you can still use arraylist for all of the work and then trim it: Collections.sort(list = new ArrayList()); list.trimToSize();

Answer (score 2):

The very smallest sorted Collection is an `ArrayList`; it's not much bigger than the underlying array. The contents are sorted if you call `sort()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not store them as [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap)s?  They're fast, small, and effective.  If that's too complicated you can look at several other types of heap implementations.  Many heaps can be stored as an array.  This means you only need as much storage space as you have objects in your collection.

Comment: fibonacci are not memory efficient

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeSet` has decent memory conservation and for time performance offers *O(log n)* insert/lookup.

Answer (score 0):

ImmutableSortedSet from [google-collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com) is the smallest thing I know of to satisfy your requirement ("sorted collection implementation"), but is not modifiable.